# Rotary Steam Engine

Tags: thermodynamics

Leon Crux invented the concept of interlocking archimedes spirals that eventually led to the [scroll compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_compressor) but intended it to be used as a rotary steam engine. However technological limitations of his day prevented the rotary steam engine from being built. Has one ever been built? What type of efficiency would one have?

Comment: See video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZzelNs1crs

Comment: @KyleKanos That is a [Jonova Rotary Steam Engine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonova_engine) There are [many pistonless rotary engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistonless_rotary_engine).

Comment: Your question states, "Has [a rotary steam engine] ever been built?"; I suppose you mean "Has Crux's version of the rotary steam engine ever been built?"

Comment: This really sounds like an engineering question to me...